# Getting 2-d array pattern from user inputs in python

Tags: python, user-input, multidimensional-array

I want to give the user input pattern as
input1: `00,01,10,11` 
and another input as 
input2: `0.1,0.2,0.24,0.5` 
and these inputs I am giving alternate value as one by one from these two inputs. For giving user input I am using:
`input = int(raw_input())`.
But my desired output should be in separate 2-d array as `[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]` and `[[0.1],[0.2],[0.24],[0.5]]` please give me good idea for this.

Comment: Your rules for parsing user input are not clear. Should `0.11` become `[0.1, 1]` or `[0.11]`, for example? Should `111` be `[1, 1, 1]`, `[11, 1]`, or `[1, 11]`? Should the values in the inner lists be integers, strings, floats...? Look into [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: If the input is 000,010,101,111, what's the output? I can't follow you clearly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe actually the input1 is in binary and input2 is in float.And output pattern is as given above

Comment: @Latik please update your question with clearer descriptions of: 1. the input data you are expecting; 2. your rules for interpreting it; and 3. what you have written so far.

Comment: @zybjtu the output should be in 2-d pattern as [[0,0,0],[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[1,1,1]], actually these values are in binary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to convert the string input into a list of substrings:

```
"0.1,0.2".split(",") == ["0.1", "0.2"]
```

and [`map`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) to apply some processing rule to those substrings; in your second case, this is conversion to `float`:

```
map(float, "0.1,0.2".split(",")) == [0.1, 0.2]
```

Your first example (binary strings to lists of integers) will require a custom function for `map`, for example:

```
map(lambda s: map(int, s), "001,010".split(",")) == [[0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
```

Note that in Python 3.x [`map`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#map) is an iterator, so you may need to explicitly convert it to a `list`.

Comment: here we are giving the value directly but what I want is the value should be given as user input i.e.  input = int(raw_input())

Comment: Then either assign the user input to a name then process it: `ui = raw_input(prompt); input = map(float, ui.split(","))` or put `raw_input` into the appropriate place, e.g. `input = map(float, raw_input(prompt).split(","))`

Comment: here I am getting error as NameError: name 'prompt' is not defined

Comment: Yes, you will need to define `prompt`, i.e. the message that the user should see requesting their input. For example, `prompt = "Enter binary strings, separated by commas: "`

Comment: ok.. I got this but still the output is not in 2-d array, it is giving as [0.1,0.21,0.114] and what i want is [[0.1],[0.21],[0.114]]

Comment: Then you will need to create your own `lambda` processing rule to both convert to `float` and put into a `list`