# Getting inputs from the text file and storing as 2-d pattern in python

Tags: python, arrays, floating-point, text-files, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have the text file contents as:

```
00   0.21 
11   0.12
10   2.51
01   0.25
```

Where the first column is binary and the second column is float value. After reading to the text file my output should be in the following 2-d array format:

```
input1 = [[0,0],[1,1],[1,0],[0,1]]
input2 = [[0.21],[0.12],[2.51],[0.25]]
```

please give any idea to obtain this output.

Comment: Have you tried using the csv module? http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: @MrE No, as I am new to python I know only to read or write a file as a line by line, so I will try to understand your given link.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting 2-d array pattern from user inputs in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174041/getting-2-d-array-pattern-from-user-inputs-in-python)

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes, but after that I realized that giving inputs from a text file is comfortable for my requirements.

Comment: Why not make each row, rather than column, equivalent to your previous input strings; then you can use the same code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `split`.

```
for line in file:
    binColumn, floatColumn = line.split()
    input1.append(list(map(int, binColumn)))
    input2.append([float(floatColumn)])
```

Comment: `list(0.21)` would raises `TypeError`.

Comment: this is what I actually want as per my requirement, thnx

Comment: @apai can you tell what to do for exact reverse of this. Means if I want to write the same pattern on txt file.

Comment: Sure, you iterate over your inputs instead. So something like: for row in range(len(input1)): print(input1[row], input2[row]) #written to file and formatted however you want it.

Answer (score 1):

Here an example using the proposed csv-module.

```
import csv

with open ('egal', 'r') as f:
    #Filtering away empty items
    #If there is a neater way, please advice
    lines = [[x for x in x if x] for x in csv.reader(f, delimiter = ' ')]

print(lines)
input1, input2 = zip(*lines)
input1 = [[int(x) for x in x] for x in input1]
input2 = [[float(x)] for x in input2]
print(input1)
print(input2)
```

Example output:

```
[['00', '0.21'], ['11', '0.12'], ['10', '2.51'], ['01', '0.25']]
[[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 0], [0, 1]]
[[0.21], [0.12], [2.51], [0.25]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You said that you are reading in a text file. It would appear that you are reading in a text line such as

```
inline = '00 0.21'
```

You would use split to get

```
inlst = inline.split(' ')
```

which produces

```
['00', '0.21']
```

given

```
input1 = []
input2 = []
```

You now use

```
input1.append((inlst[0][0], inlst[0][1]))
input2.append(float(inlst[1]))
```

This now adds the appropriate entries to your lists. Now just put this in the loop over your line reading logic.